# GetExtensionObject in XSLT thowing an error

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-2.0, biztalk

I am using below code to add namespace to context in map

```
mapInfo.Arguments.AddExtensionObject(_xslContextAccessor.namespaceuri, _xslContextAccessor);
```

but sometimes it's thowring an error

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'test'  Key being added: 'test'"
```

Is there any way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is not to add it again.  Be careful, it fells more likely you're real problem is reusing a static or similar concurrency issue.

If you have to re-add, you can do a RemoveExtensionObject() first.  This method will always complete, even if the Object doesn't exist in the collection.

Comment: Yes it is a concurrency issue. I do have RemoveExtensionObject() first but still its throwing same error.

Comment: Could this be an issue. In code mapInfo vriable is defined as "private MapInfo mapInfo;" if I change this to private MapInfo mapInfo = new MapInfo();" will that solve the issue in concurrent env.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse a compiled Map?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to reuse a complied map.

Comment: Well, then you just need to follow you code path carefully to make sure the MapInfo is set only once.